# Xamarin iOS opens and immediately closes

Tags: debugging, xamarin.ios

My Xamarin iOS app will build successfully, however, during launch it will flash the launch screen and immediately return to my phones home screen exiting my app without an error. 
Upon reviewing Xamarin Studio, the status appears at top:

`Waiting for debugger to connect to Phone on port 10000 view USB...`

and simply hangs.

How can this be alleviated?

Comment: If you run xcode -> window devices, select the device. There you can view any ios output. The output there when launching the app could help find the problem.

Comment: I got this to work. I had not updated the info.plist with the proper code to permit Facebooks domains, rolled out for iOS 9 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios, this is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just right click on your project and set it as a startup project. I solved the same problem and it launches the app properly without closing it.